# Unable to use recursion

Tags: python

Problem link = https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-operations-to-reduce-x-to-zero/

Was practicing on leetcode and came around the above the Q. Wrote the code written below, no idea why it is not running!

```
def min_num(nums,x):
    
    f_ele = nums[0]
    l_ele = nums[-1]
    count = 0

    if min(x - f_ele, x - l_ele ) >= 0:
        count += 1
        #modifying x and nums
        if x - f_ele == min(x - f_ele, x - l_ele ):
            x = x - f_ele
            nums.remove(f_ele)  
        else:
            x = x - l_ele
            nums.remove(l_ele) 
        
        #Comparing x to use recursion or return the count
        if x != 0: 
            min_num(nums,x)
        else:
            return count

    elif x == 0:
        return count
    
    else:
        return -1
```

Please help!!

Comment: Assuming you actually _run_ your function somehow, did you try following the execution step by step in a debugger, for example [Python Tutor Visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)? If so, what did you find - where does it stray off the path you expected?

Comment: What value do you think you're returning after the call `min_num(nums,x)` has completed? Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions, so you can understand your issue by thinking about `if x != 0: x else: return count`

Comment: BTW: you have `min_num([1,2], 1) == -1`, but it should be 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for the debugger, I got the answer for this Q, but it will surely help me in future Q

Comment: As for getting min_num([1,2], 1) == -1, I think I need to use abs() function. Never actually thought that x can get negative. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you do recursion and want to return something you need to also return the result from the recursion itself.

You also can't set the count to zero in the min_num function because then the count will constantly be set to zero when you run the recursion.

Here is your code with these two small changes:

```
def min_num(nums, x, count=0):

    f_ele = nums[0]
    l_ele = nums[-1]

    if min(x - f_ele, x - l_ele) >= 0:
        count += 1
        # modifying x and nums
        if x - f_ele == min(x - f_ele, x - l_ele):
            x = x - f_ele
            nums.remove(f_ele)
        else:
            x = x - l_ele
            nums.remove(l_ele)

        # Comparing x to use recursion or return the count
        if x != 0:
            return min_num(nums, x, count)
        else:
            return count

    elif x == 0:
        return count

    else:
        return -1


nums = [1, 1, 4, 2, 3]
x = 5

print(min_num(nums, x))
```

This returns 2

Answer (score -1):

```
def find_min(x,arrayin):
    if (len(arrayin)==0 or x==-1):
        return -1

    elif x==0:
        return len(arrayin)


    left=arrayin[0]
    right=arrayin[len(arrayin)-1]

    if  x-min(left,right)<0:
        return  find_min(-1,arrayin)

    if x-max(left,right)>=0:
        if left>right: ##Remove left
            return find_min(x-left,arrayin[1:len(arrayin)])
        
        else:##Remove right
            return find_min(x-right,arrayin[0:len(arrayin)-1])

    elif  x-min(left,right)>=0:
        if   left>right: ##Remove left
            return find_min(x-right,arrayin[0:len(arrayin)-1])
        
        else:
            return find_min(x-left,arrayin[1:len(arrayin)])





nums = [3,2,20,1,1,3]
x = 10

res=find_min(x,nums)
if res==-1:
    print("-1")

else:
    Answer=len(nums)-res
    print(str(Answer))
```